# Is it possible to complete my Windows Character Map?

Tags: character, ascii, extended-ascii

I'd like to access unusual letters such as Đ, Ħ, Ŋ or Ř directly from the  keyboard on Windows (I can't copy-paste in the context I intend to use them).
However my Character Map shows blanks where they should appear, and (presumably for this reason) the Alt+ combinations don't work.

Why can't I type characters that evidently exist, seeing as I can copy them?
Example : if I type alt+331, which should give lowercase ŋ, I get K; in fact all alt+ beyond 256 seem to act mod 255.

This is bothering me more than it might seem, so thanks for any answer.

Comment: I think your Character Map info doesn't relate to the problem. It shows in mine. Perhaps your selected font doesn't support it. Arial works for me.

Comment: Use a Unicode-complete font, like Segoe UI, Roboto, Source Sans Pro, etc.

Comment: Also, I've flagged this as off-topic, since it's not got anything to do with programming. Perhaps you should post this on SuperUser

Comment: OK thanks. I'll move it right after then.
I've installed all imaginable fonts, including the 3 you mention, and still I can't type alt+330 to get my letter, and hexadecimal writing doesn't work on my computer.
Why is this? What troubles me is that I assume I have a good enough font, considering I can see Ŋ (Old English letter Eng) on Internet.

Comment: Again, being able to see it and being able to type it are two different things.